# Functional equation: $f(x)=\frac x{\prod_{i|x}^{x-1} f(i)}$

Tags: functional-equations

Find an algebraic function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that

$$f(x)=\frac x{\prod_{i|x}^{x-1} f(i)}$$

and

$$f(1)=1$$

for all $x\in\Bbb N$

I allready know two things:

1. $f(p^k)=p$ where $p$ is prime and $k\in\Bbb N$
2. $f(apq)=1$ where $p$ and $q$ is two different primes and $a\in\Bbb N$

I'm looking for a specific function, not just an algorithm.

Comment: $$f(x) = x\left(\prod_{i | x, i < x} f(i)\right)^{-1} = x f(x) \left(\prod_{i | x} f(i)\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: Thanks for the notation tip, user1952009

Comment: you get that if $p$ is prime : $f(p) = p$ hence $f(p^2) = p, f(p^k) = p, f(p q) = \ldots$ ?

Comment: The stuff you "already know" entirely defines the function. @OskarVikhamar-Sandberg

Answer (score 1):

You have $$n = \prod_{d\mid n} f(d)$$ so you can use the product version of Möbius inversion to get:

$$f(n)=\prod_{d\mid n} d^{\mu(n/d)}$$

Not sure if that helps, nor if there isn't some other, simpler closed form.

For $n=p^k$ with $p$ prime, we see this is $f(p^k)=\frac{p^k}{p^{k-1}}=p$.

For $n=p^aq^b$, this is $$\frac{(p^aq^b)(p^{a-1}q^{b-1})}{(p^{a-1}q^b)(p^aq^{b-1})}=1$$

I'm guessing it is $f(p^k)=p$ and $f(n)=1$ for $n$ not a prime power.

It certainly seems to work...